# GWT - Detect different screen resolutions while running

Tags: events, gwt

I want my app to change different parts of the UI when the resolution is big enough and is on landscape mode, and detect changes while the app is running (screen rotation on a mobile device, for instance).

I know that I should have an event listen to the screen resolution (which can be obtained via javascript), but I don't know how to do this. How do I hang an event on a always refreshing value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `Window.addResizeHandler`

```
Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
        yourCustomLayoutAdjustmentMethod(event.getHeight(), event.getWidth());
    }
});
```

No JavaScript required!

Answer (score 5):

with **MGWT** library (http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/) :

import these classes

```
import com.googlecode.mgwt.dom.client.event.orientation.OrientationChangeEvent;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.dom.client.event.orientation.OrientationChangeEvent.ORIENTATION;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.dom.client.event.orientation.OrientationChangeHandler;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.MGWT;
```

define an orientation handler

```
class MyOrientationChangeHandler implements OrientationChangeHandler {
    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(OrientationChangeEvent event) {
        switch (event.getOrientation()) {
            case LANDSCAPE:
                // handle landscape orientation
                return;
            case PORTRAIT:
                // handle portrait orientation
                return;

        }
    }
}
```

add your handler

```
MGWT.addOrientationChangeHandler(new MyOrientationChangeHandler ());
```