# java code for google web toolkit development.

Tags: java, gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GWT - Detect different screen resolutions while running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096657/gwt-detect-different-screen-resolutions-while-running)

How do I write a code in java for google web toolkit which will set the screen of the web browser according to the screen resolution of the computer?

My problem is each time I change the screen resolution the components of the web application look  stretched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should also resize your container widget when the user resizes the window. I've had a similar problem using the `TabLayoutPanel`.

```
Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {           
  public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {             
  yourWidget.setHeight(event.getHeight() + "px");
  yourWidget.setWidth(event.getWidth() + "px");
}
});
```